# Python dict with default value based on key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, defaultdict

I need a dictionary that is automatically filled with a default value for each accessed key that is missing. I've found `defaultdict` and some other ways to achieve this, but the problem in my case is that I want the default value for each key to be specific to the key itself.

For example, with `defaultdict` I can achieve something like this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(lambda: 5)
> d[1] = 3
> d[1]
> 3
> d[2]
> 5
```

But what if I need the default value for each accessed missing key to be for example `key + 5`? Something like:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(lambda key: key + 5)  # <-- This does not work as defaultdict expects lambda function to be without any parameters
> d[1] = 3
> d[1]
> 3
> d[2]
> 7         <- Calculated from accessed key + 5 (2+5)
> d[5]
> 10        <- Calculated from accessed key + 5 (5+5)
```

Is there a clean, builtin way to achieve what I need? I know that I can create a subclass of dict and implement this specific functionality at `__getitem__` level, but I want to avoid that if possible.

I couldn't find a solution in other answers, so sorry if it is still a duplicate.

Comment: Why do you think your current way is not *clean*?

Comment: `defaultdict` only works with lambda functions without parameters, so the second example is not a working python code.

Comment: It's just showing what kind of functionality I want to end up with

Comment: Oh, OK. I thought this is the current behavior and you want further improvements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there is a builtin way of doing this. However, instead of subclassing `dict` and change `getitem`, you can subclass [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) itself to tell `__missing__()` to call the `default_factory` with an argument (the `key`), rather than without args. It is still a custom class, not a builtin, but it should be quite efficient still.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

class DefaultDict(defaultdict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return self.default_factory(key)
```

Then:

```py
d = DefaultDict(lambda key: key + 5)

d[2]
# 7
```

Comment: Even though I wanted to avoid creation of a subclass, this seems like the best solution for now, so I'll accept this answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a function like this

```
dic = {}
DEFAULT_VALUE = 5

def dict_get(item):
    try:
        return [dic[item]]
    except:
        dic[int(item)] = DEFAULT_VALUE + int(item)
        return DEFAULT_VALUE + int(item)

print(dict_get(10))
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that dic is searched twice for the key (if the key is missing): first time it searches for it when you try to return, then it searches again when you insert the key (it's the default behaviour: whenever you try to insert a key the dict first checks if the key is already present or not). If the dict is huge, it matters. defauldict from the standard library avoids this double search.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it without creating any class. You can use [dict.setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=setdefault#dict.setdefault):

```py
d = {}
d_default_factory = lambda key: key + 5
d.setdefault(2, d_default_factory(2))
# 7
```

Optionally, you could save the default factory as an entry in the dictionary, like so:

```py
d = {'default_factory': lambda key: key + 5}
d.setdefault(2, d['default_factory'](2))
# 7
```