# Python dict: Make a key resolve to itself

Tags: python

Given the following dict

```py
CV = { a: [a, b], b: [b, c], c: [c], d: [d] }
```

Let's say I am lazy and I want to have the dictionary return a value that references the key, something like

```py
CV = { a: [a, b], b: [b, c], _: [_] }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: No, it is not...

Comment: Honestly I don't understand what you're asking :(

Comment: What's the question? If a, b, c and _ all exists, that CV line works

Comment: I suppose you could use something like a dict comprehension to write all the reflexive entries somewhat shorter.

Comment: If you want to have a dictionary that for a missing key `k` returns `[k]` by default, you can do that by subclassing `dict`. Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: Or use `dict.get(key, [key])`.

Comment: @khelwood Yes, I am looking for a way to get a dict to return some default values implicitly. Maybe that's a bit too much for a dict, so I'm thinking about wrapping it in a function that handles the default part, instead of using `.get()` and repeat the default return value multiple times.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want, for missing keys, to return a value based on a function called with the missing key? In that case look here: [python-dict-with-default-value-based-on-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65901825/python-dict-with-default-value-based-on-key)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.get()` method and set the key as the default values as well:

```
>>> my_dict = {"a": [1], "b": [2]}
>>> my_dict.get("a", ["a"])
[1]
>>> my_dict.get("c", ["c"])
['c']
>>>
```